# Is cosmology and evolution possible with anti-matter?

Tags: cosmology, antimatter, stellar-evolution

Suppose the universe had more anti-matter than matter. (I mean the exact reverse ratio to the real universe)

- Would there be galaxies?
- Would there be stars?
- Would there be heat and light?
- Would there be planets?
- Would there be life?

Why/Why not?

Comment: Why not? we all would be made of antibaryons(antiprotons) and anti leptons(antielectrons)......and over time everyone would realize that calling every particle anti-something takes time and doesnt make sense when there are more of the anti than the regular ones. And somebody else would say , hey lets call the anti particles....as just particles....and the particles as antiparticles.....save everyone some time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, sure! The galaxies and planets and people would just be antimatter, except that when they got to figuring out that there was another kind of matter, they'd probably call themselves matter and the other kind antimatter. There's really no reason for there not to be. Of course, it's a good thing it is the same ratio as our universe, just flipped, because antimatter-matter collisions would still annihilate each other.

Hope this helps!